# How to grant access to Salesforce checkout

Tags: salesforce, admin, checkout

Here's one that seems to puzzle everyone, including my Salesforce rep.

I setup a trial of a Force.com platform org.  I'm logged in as the administrator, and want to convert it to a paid subscription, so I start looking for a Checkout link.  It's not in the App menu where some help pages say it should be.
[Image of app menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dDJio.png)
nor is it at the bottom of the left nav stack in Setp where you often see it.  Nor is it on the System overview page.

I've searched this on the SF community and online.  Everyone, including my rep says I just need to edit myself as a user and check "Checkout Enabled".

And yet, I cannot find this on this User edit screen, or on any of the other profile or permission set screens.
[User edit screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O4vwP.png)

I'm clearly missing something obvious.  What is it?

Answer (score 0):

So I've just heard from my Salesforce sales rep, and she had to have someone in Salesforce OPS turn on Checkout for me.   I guess there are some accounts that can't access it without vendor intervention.  If I find out differently, I will post here.